# Check constantly internet connection in java

Tags: java, wait

I am trying to check if internet is on or not constantly every 5 seconds, I wrote below code but some how it always go inside wait() and waiting infinite.

Code I wrote :

```
Socket socket = null;


public void checkInternetConnectivity() throws InterruptedException {
    boolean reachable = false;
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.x", xx);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                stopApp();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                stopApp();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    synchronized (this) {
        wait();
    }
}

private void stopApp() {
    System.out.println("Internet Not Available stopping app");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

It always stuck inside below :

```
synchronized (this) {
        wait();
    }
```

Comment: If you are waiting, someone should notify on this as well? Where is that?

Comment: if it is a scheduled task, why wait?

Comment: where do you notify()?

Comment: @SMA- I agree with you but not sure where exactly I notify here.

Comment: why would not expect it to?  Previously all you are doing is setting up a `task` to run in another thread.

Comment: Well it works for me. If I launch your application and then disconnect internet it is terminated with `java.net.SocketException: Network not available (connect failed)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
InetAddress.isReachable
```

Depending on what your needs are you should consider trying reach a specific host by

```
private static boolean googleIsAvailable() {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        connection.getInputStream().close();
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If your are communicating with a webservice the webservice should provide a GET method to check if it is available.

If you need to check constantly try somthing like

```
Socket s = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT);
while(s.isConnected()){
 //do your stuff
}
```

You should also check out the keepAlive Option.

But the more important question is what happen in your application if internet connection is not available anymore?

Most methods throw Exceptions if a Server is not available anymore.

You could just catch them and react on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it won't check constantly I think. It will check only when and where I call this function.

Comment: Updated my answer... Socket connections have a "isConnected" method